# Write attribute to scope above current one

Tags: python, oop, closures

I am wondering if there is a way to programatically write an attribute to the class of a parent in which a function is run. I am looking for something like the following.

```
def add_items():
    setattr(ParentClass, 'foo', 'bar')

class A(object):
    add_items()

class B(object):
    add_items()


a = A()
b = B()
print a.foo
"bar"
print b.foo
"bar"
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no direct way to do it. You can try using `inspect` module, but the most interesting (in your case) information it will give is the name of the caller object (`A` or `B`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. But if you just want to customize your class creation(say, write an attribute to class when it is created), you can use metaclass other than a function call. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=metaclass#customizing-class-creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are after.  Here are two attempts to answer your question.

You can make a decorator which adds attributes to a class:

```
def add_items(cls):
    cls.foo = "bar"
    return cls

@add_items
class A(object):
    pass
```

On the other hand, if your function is a method, it can add whatever attributes it wants to the class instance:

```
class B(object):
    def add_items(self):
        self.foo = 'Baz'

b = B()
b.add_items()
```

Comment: I guess it's not what OP wants, since he asks about the scope

Comment: The decorator is the best answer for what I'm looking for Thanks!